# how to overcome this error `Vehicle.CreateObject(int, string, int, string)': not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#-4.0

/*I am a beginner to C#. I tried to create a simple vehicle details. My constrain is - i want these methods to be include in my program.1- public Vehicle CreateObject(int lNo, String bName) but while compiling  -error CS0161: `Vehicle.CreateObject(int, string, int, string)': not all code paths return a value and I am not sure what happening in this call public string DisplayDetails(Vehicle v). I have an idea what the method is doing there. But i can't understand what happening in (Vehicle v) on that place  */

```
using System;

public class Vehicle
{
    public int licenseNo;
    public String brandName;
    public int noOfWheels;
    public string color;

    public Vehicle CreateObject( int lNo, String bName,int wheels, String colour)
    {
        licenseNo = lNo;
        brandName = bName;
        noOfWheels = wheels;
        color = colour;
    }

    public String DisplayDetails(Vehicle v)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(licenseNo);
        Console.WriteLine(brandName);
        Console.WriteLine(noOfWheels);
        return color;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter license number,brand name, no of wheels and color for vehicle");
        v1.licenseNo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        v1.brandName = Console.ReadLine();
        v1.noOfWheels = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        v1.color = Console.ReadLine();
        v1.DisplayDetails();
        Console.WriteLine(v1.color);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of cleaning up your indents. In future posts, please indent and space your code properly. If you don't put any indents at all in your code it's much more difficult to read, and you are less likely to get an answer if you torture your readers in this fashion. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you haven't returned a value in your `CreateObject` method.

If you want a method to not return a value (which you don't here, because it wouldn't make much sense) you'd have to say `public void CreateObject(etc.)`. You are declaring that you are going to return a `Vehicle` object and failing to do so.

That said, your whole concept is off. You don't want to use `CreateObject` here; you need a constructor. [Here's the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors) on constructors. I suggest you take a look at it.

That said, just get rid of `CreateObject`, so:

```
public Vehicle (int lNo, String bName,int wheels, String colour)
{ //etc.
```

That will put the constructor in proper syntax. `CreateObject` is something to use if you are using Interop to create COM objects, and you're not trying to do that here.

Comment: Thank you BobRodes !! For your consideration. I had gone through the documents you attached here. But in my program i need to use the (public  Vehicle CreateObject( int lNo,String bName, int wheels, String colour) -This method creates and returns a Vehicle object ). I don't have depth knowledge in it. I want to learn how to program for this. If you don't mine please let u explain me.

Comment: @mohamedimran Where are you getting your requirements from? First you say that you need to use `CreateObject` and then you say you don't have knowledge of it. If you don't have knowledge of it, then how do you know that you need to use `CreateObject`?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

public class Vehicle
{
    public int licenseNo;
    public String brandName;
    public int noOfWheels;
    public string color;

    public Vehicle CreateObject(int lNo,String bName,int wheels,String colour)
    {
        Vehicle v = new Vehicle();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter license number,brand name,no of wheels and color for vehicle");
        licenseNo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        brandName = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        noOfWheels = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        color = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        return v;
    }
    public String DisplayDetails(Vehicle v)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("License Number: {0}",licenseNo);
        Console.WriteLine("Brand Name: {0}",brandName);
        Console.WriteLine("No of Wheels: {0}",noOfWheels);
        Console.ReadKey();
        return color; 
    }

}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int lNo,wheels;
        String bName="";
        String colour="";
        Vehicle v = new Vehicle();
        lNo = v.licenseNo;
        bName = v.brandName;
        wheels = v.noOfWheels;
        colour = v.color;
        v.CreateObject(lNo,bName,wheels,colour);
        v.DisplayDetails(v);
        Console.WriteLine("Color: {0}",v.color);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```